# What is the Fourier series for $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ from $0$ to $1$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, bessel-functions

I want to calculate the Fourier series for the periodic function $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ for $0<x<1$.
The DC term is easy to find, it’s just $a_n$ and $b_n$ that I can’t quite figure out.
Basically, my question is how is this integral solved?:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1-x^2}\cos(2n\pi x)\,dx $$

I’ve tried the substitution $x=\sin(\theta)$ but I didn’t really get anywhere.

Also, does this lead to Bessel Functions in any way? I saw some similarities when I looked them up, but I couldn’t reach an answer.
I would appreciate it if anyone could help me with this.
Thanks.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5BCos%5B2*Pi*n*x%5D*Sqrt%5B1-x%5E2%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%5D) which follows from http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9.E4

Comment: @Gary Thank you so much for your help!